# Fill combobox with time values

Tags: vb.net

I want fill my combobox with time values like (08:00, 08:10, 08:20 until 09:50) step=10 minutes but the result is like (8:00, 8:10, 8:20, 8:30, 9:-20,9:-10, 9:00, 9:10, 9:20).
My code doesn't show the value like 8:40, 8:50 and he also show negative value like 9:-20, 9:-10).
So please how can I resolve this problem?

```
Heure_rdv.Items.Clear()
    Dim nbr_minute2 As String
    For i = 480 To 590 Step 10
        Dim nbr_heure As Integer = cint(i / 60)
        Dim nbr_minute As Integer = (i - (nbr_heure * 60))
        nbr_minute2 = CStr(nbr_minute) + "0"
        If ((i - (nbr_heure * 60)) = 0) Then

            Heure_rdv.Items.Add(CStr(nbr_heure) + ":" + nbr_minute2)
        Else

            Heure_rdv.Items.Add(CStr(nbr_heure) + ":" + CStr(nbr_minute))

        End If




    Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I should do try it in VBA.
Should be similar in VB.NET

```
DIM i As Integer 'Counter 1
Dim ii As Integer 'Counter 2
' make 1st loop for hours
for i = 8 To 9
  ' mkae 2nd loop for minutes
  for ii = 0 To 50 Step 10
     ' 
     Heure_rdv.Items.Add(i & ":" & ii)
  next
next
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be done with fewer lines of code using linq

```
Dim steps = Enumerable.Range(0,6)
Dim items as List(Of String) = new List(Of String)()
items.AddRange(steps.Select(Function(x) "08:" & (x * 10).ToString("D2")))
items.AddRange(steps.Select(Function(x) "09:" & (x * 10).ToString("D2")))
Heure_rdv.DataSource = items
```

First we create a list of integers from 0 to 5 (6 elements), then using these elements we create the strings required multiplying each element of the integer list by ten and converting the result to a two digit string. We do this one time for the 8 hour and one time for the 9. Finally we could set the combo datasource to the resulting list of strings.

Comment: Thanks but an error occur   "Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[System.Int32,System.String]' en type 'System.Object[]'."

Comment: Right, we should use the DataSource property to set in a single step the list of strings with the time intervals.